# CenOS 6.5 Apache 2.2 Django Project gives / 403

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, httpd, django

I have `Apache 2.2` running over `CentOS 6.5` for first time. I faced no problem with Ubuntu with configurations below, but on CentOS always giving me `403` error. The `example.com` domain is living under Ubuntu server right now. If I can be able to run it under CentOS, I'll redirect example.com to CentOS server. But now I'm trying to run it with `test.example.com` domain. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Error that I faced:

```
[Mon Jun 23 15:30:40 2014] [error] [client ip] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

Virtual Host conf:

```
NameVirtualHost ip:80
<VirtualHost ip:80>

    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias test.example.com

    <Directory /home/user/example>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess example user=user group=user python-path=/home/user/example:/home/user/example/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=2 threads=25 inactivity-timeout=60 maximum-requests=100
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/example/project/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog  /home/user/example/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /home/user/example/logs/access_log combined

    Alias /media/ /home/user/example/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/user/example/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're running the project from `/home/user`, are you sure you configured SElinux correctly? Normally, Apache has no business in home directories and will be rejected access by the standard SElinux policy.

Comment: selinux is disabled already. Should I enable it?

Comment: I'd recommend against disabling SElinux, but if you've already done so, we know that SElinux is not the problem here. Does Apache (`httpd`) have read access on the filesystem?

Comment: I double checked httpd.conf. It says User and group name is `apache` and I change `/home/user/example` group to `apache`. Also Folder permissions (755) and file permissions(644) are correct. I think this is not the problem because I see the apache can log under project folder. Now I checked for user folder permissions. It looks `700`. Is this the problem?

Comment: Nope thats not the problem I guess. When I changed /home/user to 755 Apache said `Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'project' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.985.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.`

Comment: Sounds to me like that solved your problem, but now you've got another problem. Try googling this one. It certainly seems odd to me to try and put a socket in `/etc/httpd/logs` (which is a symlink to `/var/log/httpd`).

Comment: If proper way is moving project to under the `/var/www` I'll move the project. Do you know any document, specifically for serving django projects under CentOS.

Comment: I got a pretty comprehensive guide by just googling for `django centos`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I must think more simplistic. Unfortunately I did not think to search docs with just two words. I used much longer strings, but I failed. That was awesome. Thanks again. :)